# creating small JavaScript project and it is not running through chrome

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, browser

I am just starting to read Head First Javascript Programming and im doing one of the first practice examples the "99 bottles of beer on the wall" using variables, while loops, and else if statements,  im trying to run this in Visual-Studio-Code and when I click run through chrome another file tab pops up that says {} settings.json, how can I run this so that I can see if my app is working?

Comment: what does the book say how you should run the program, just open the html file in Chrome directly, and see if that works

Comment: I apologize i am very new to all of this im not sure how to go about doing this i've tried clicking run and then run without debugging the book does not say how to run the program.

Comment: the `Head First` books are written for the absolute beginners, so they must explain how to run the programs they discuss

Comment: read the VSC doc pages on how to run/debug Node.JS scripts